# Create a parent -> children hierarchy from two collections

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.5, linq-to-objects

I have two separate collections instances filled with data

```
List<Parent> parents;
List<Child> children;
```

two collections can be connected through Child.ParentId, and Parent.Children.

parents collection does not have Children property populated, so how can I link Parent objects with Children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = from d in parents  
             join s in children  
             on d.ParentID equals s.ParentID into g  
             select new  
             {  
                 ParentName = d.ParentName,  
                 ChildList = g  
             };

foreach (var item in result)  
{  
    Console.WriteLine("Parent: {0}", item.ParentName);  
    foreach (var Child in item.ChildList)  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine(Child.Name);  
    }  
    Console.WriteLine();  
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. Just to be clear, this is a left join operation, parents without children will still be present?

Comment: this is Grouped Join, and this is used when we want hierarchical data structure , yes parent without child will be present.

Answer (score 1):

```
 children.Join(parents,
                c => c.ParentId,
                p => p.ParentId,
                (c, p) => new { children = c, parents = p })
                .Select(x => x.parents).ToList();
```

**Update**

```
var result = parents.Join(children,
                     p => p.ParentId,
                     c => c.ParentId,
                     (p,c) => new { parents = p,children = c  })
                     .Select(x => new
                     {
                         ParentName = x.parents.ParentName,  
                         ChildList= x.children
                     })
                     //.GroupBy(x=>x.ParentName )
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: @goran- this code will just gv me parent data rit? based on the join,  will this provide an hierarchy??